# Multiple circuit on raspberry

Tags: pi-3, gpio, python, raspbian-jessie

Can I create two circuit on one raspberry?
I want to create automated watering system for my home plants.
There will be two components in this system
1) water pump controlled through Relay system
2) steeper motor (with pipe attached) which will pour water in different buckets. These buckets will have pipes connected till plant
I tried searching similar project on net but not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create as many circuits as you want and connect them to the Pi at the same time.

There will be overall limits, e.g.

- the Pi's with the 40 pin expansion header have 28 GPIO available for use
- the Pi will not be able to run multiple CPU intensive algorithms at the same time.

The only way to see if you will hit a limit is to construct your design and check.

Comment: Thanks Joan.  I am newbie to circuits design. I will try to sketch it on paper and add here.